# Use of "where" to add details

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, complements

I wrote:

> For example, to extract the price field from a product and save it as a distinct XML node inside the product’s node, an appropriate pattern can be defined using the “price” handle and the “Self” option **where its parent pattern is set to the “Products” pattern**.

I have seen patterns like "There is X and Y, where X is ....". But in my case it is like "There is X and Y, where W is the ...". Is *where* applicable even if the clause after it has no reference to the other details?
What is the grammatical role of "where" here?

However, in my sentence **its parent pattern** means the parent of the pattern that is defined in this way (by using "price" handle and "Self" option.

Are there other ways so I can add the detail shown in bold?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is fine and no additional detail is required -- assuming you want the bolded phrase to apply to the "Self" option.  Otherwise it's not clear what the phrase is meant to modify.

Here's how I interpret your sentence:

> (to save the price field as a distinct XML node) define a pattern using the "price" handle and set the "Self" option.  The parent pattern of the "Self" option will be set to the "Products" pattern.

If this is not correct, then you should either reorganize the sentence, or add additional information.

Comment: I refined my question to say what is my purpose of the *where clause*.

Comment: It's still not clear without additional context, but then that's not uncommon for technical documentation.  In this case I would recommend a *list* of instructions: "In order to accomplish X, do A, B, and C."

Comment: you mean to substitute "where" with "and" and on other change is required?